# How do I factor sweep and dihedral in the lift equation?

Tags: lift, wing-sweep

I'm guessing that you add cos(angle of dihedral) to calculate lift loss by dihedral, but I'm not sure how to factor in the lift loss by the wing swept. Could someone help me include lift loss due to dihedral and sweep? Thank you 
Note: I mean without factoring it into the lift coefficient.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid 'factoring it [wing sweep] into the lift coefficient'. The sweep changes the angle of attack response (reducing the lift slope in the first place, but not only that), rather than lift per se. If you linearise though, then it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snorri Gudmundsson's "General Aviation Aircraft Design"'s equation 9-57 allows you to estimate the lift coefficient curve's linear slope for trapezoidal/swept wings:
[image: Eq. 9-57]

Note: the equation is in radians, not degrees

As for the dihedral, Equation 9-33 estimates the impact on angle of attack and Equation 9-35 estimates the resulting lift force:

[image: Eq. 9-33]

[image: Eq. 9-35]

Let me know if it's not what you wanted, though, I didn't quite get the "without factoring it into the lift coefficient." part - isn't the question's title about how it impacts the lift coefficient?